# Throwing elements of a node list on stack

Tags: java, list, stack

I'm using Java and I have a list of nodes, which I need on a Stack in the order from last to first, using List.

Example:

my list is {node1,node2,node3}

my stack is supposed to be

{

node1,

node2,

node3

}

How do I solve this easily?

Would this work?

```
if (hasWhiteNeighbor(startNode)) {
        List<Node> conNodes = getAdjacentNodes(startNode);
        while (conNodes.size() > 0) {
            int conCount = conNodes.size();
            stack.push(conNodes.get(conCount));
            conNodes.remove(conCount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Comment: stack in my country is the same as LIFO (Last In First Out)

Comment: Uhm, yes? What's the problem? I need the elements in this order.

Answer (score 0):

Because List guarantees the order of iteration to be the same as the order in which the elements were added, you can solve this problem easily by simply adding the nodes to the list in the correct order, then iterating through the list and adding each element to the stack.

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("node1");
stringList.add("node2");
stringList.add("node3");

Deque<String> stringStack = new ArrayDeque<String>();
for (String s : stringList) {
  stringStack.push(s);
}

while (!stringStack.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println(stringStack.pop());
}
```

The above code produces this output:

```
node3
node2
node1
```

Links
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Comment: You should advice that STACK is not recommended for LIFO. `A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class`